# Projections from a curve on $\mathbb{P}^1\times E$ are covering maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

In the book [Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface] by Mumford, Example 3 on p.2 says the projections $C\to \mathbb{P}^1$, $C\to E$ are covering maps where $E$ is an elliptic curve over $k$ and $C$ is a curve on $\mathbb{P}^1\times E$.

Does this mean the underlying topological maps of $C\to \mathbb{P}^1$, $C\to E$ are covering maps in the sense of topology? If it does, may I ask why?

Comment: No, it means that in all nontrivial cases the projections are finite flat morphisms. If you're over the complex numbers, then in the analytic topology the underlying topological maps are coverings in the sense of topology iff moreover the morphism is étale.

Comment: @Rieux Thanks for the comment! Does "the covering" in the book just mean the map which intuitively acts like a covering map in a classical sense? (So I just want to check whether there is a rigorous definition of covering map between schemes except étale covering)

Comment: When algebraic geometers talk about a covering they usually mean a morphism that is flat, finite and dominant.  Any non-constant morphism of smooth projective curves has all of these properties.