# Explanation of a particular example in Mumford's Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Please see the picture below. I believe the claim that the maps are coverings e.g. see [this post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942429/projections-from-a-curve-on-mathbbp1-times-e-are-covering-maps). However, what I am confused about is the claim in Case ii).

If I take a cover of type $(d,e)$, then I want a $d$-fold cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and an $e$-fold cover of $\mathscr{E}$.  I do not understand how this is $d(e+1$)-dimensional and is not a linear system.

My guess on it not being a linear system is if I take a curve $C$ in this family and compute $L(C)$ and it's dimension, then this is not actually $d(e+1)$-dimensional. This would use the Riemann-Roch Theorem...

[image]

Comment: Consider for simplicity the case $e = 0$. Then $C$ is the pullback of a divisor of degree $d$ on the elliptic curve $E$. Such divisors on $E$ form an irreducible $d$-dimensional family of curves, but it is not a linear system, because different points on an elliptic curve are not linearly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I am still confused on the $d(e+1)$ dimensional computation. 

Also, I do not follow how such divisors $E$ form an irreducible $d$-dimensional family of curves. What does $d$-dimensional in your comment mean? Like I could vary points determining the degree $d$ divisor on $\mathscr{E}$ but this means I am not thinking of $d$-dimensional as over a field, but over the curve.l

Comment: The parameter space for the degree $d$ divisors on $E$ is the symmetric power $S^d(E)$. It has dimension $d$ over the field. It comes with the canonical morphism $S^d(E) \to J(E)$ to the Jacobian of the curve, which is a fiber bundle with fibers projective spaces of dimension $d - 1$, each fiber is a linear system.

Comment: This is new to me here. What exactly is $S^d(E)$ defined to be?

Comment: The quotient of $E^d$ by the symmetric group action.